# Through (collecting) body fluid, a doctor can tell if the patient has been infected or not. - What is the differece with/without "collect"?

Tags: prepositions, usage

**Example 1**

> Through body fluid, a doctor can tell if the patient has been infected by bactoria or not.

**Example 2**

> Through collecting body fluid, a doctor can tell if the patient has been infected by bactoria or not.

**Question 1**

> Are both examples correct?

**Question 2**

> What is the differece with/without "collect"?

I feel that if there is a clear context, I don't need to add "collect" after the word "through".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your surmise. The context makes the meaning clear. But both your examples are unnecessarily clumsy sentences.

The meaning could be far better expressed by saying:

**From a patient's bodily fluids, a doctor can determine whether the patient has a bacterial infection.**

There is no need to say **By collecting.....**

The word is **bacteria**, not "bactoria".